# Creating a new object in typescript based off an existing object

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript I have a base object as a template and I want to replicate that object changing just the one property similar to below:

```js
interface user {
    name: string, 
    jobTitle: string
}

const employee: user = {name: 'Liane', jobTitle: 'Web Dev'}

const newEmployee1 = employee;
newEmployee1.name = 'James';
const newEmployee2 = employee;
newEmployee2.name = 'John';
```

However when I view the results in the console every employees name is 'John' as shown below:

```js
{name: 'John', jobTitle: 'Web Dev'}
{name: 'John', jobTitle: 'Web Dev'}
{name: 'John', jobTitle: 'Web Dev'}
```

I do understand this is due to object referencing, however I don't want to reference the base employee I want to clone it as it own object independant from the other users. So when I console log the objects I'll get:

```js
{name: 'Liane', jobTitle: 'Web Dev'}
{name: 'James', jobTitle: 'Web Dev'}
{name: 'John', jobTitle: 'Web Dev'}
```

Is there any way for me to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to clone an existing object, I'd recommend the "spread operator"

```js
// interface user {
//     name: string, 
//     jobTitle: string
// }

// const employee: user = {name: 'Liane', jobTitle: 'Web Dev'}
const employee = {name: 'Liane', jobTitle: 'Web Dev'}

const newEmployee1 = {
  ...employee,
  name: 'James'
};

const newEmployee2 = {
  ...employee,
  name: 'John'
};

console.log(employee)
console.log(newEmployee1)
console.log(newEmployee2)
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use either the [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals) operator:

```js
const newEmployee1 = {
  ...employee,
  name: 'James',
};
const newEmployee2 = {
  ...employee,
  name: 'John',
};
```

Or with an `Object.assign()`:

```js
const newEmployee1 = Object.assign({}, employee);
newEmployee1.name = 'James';

const newEmployee2 = Object.assign({}, employee);
newEmployee2.name = 'John';
```

Keep in mind that neither of these are a deep clone, and non-primitive values share the same reference.